# dispalying data from NSarray to table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to **iOS** and I am trying to build an lightweight app for practice. I am taking two textfield entries from one *view controller* and storing them in `NSDictionary`. I am transferring those data in `NSArray`. Now I want to display those data from `NSArray` to *table view*. I am using this line of code:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But my app is crashing when cursor comes at this line. Help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your full `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method code. And post the Crash log you are receiving too.

Comment: Post here your full code where you are stucked so that people can see exactly where you are making mistake....

Answer (score 1):

For UITableView you have to define at least 2 methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

It seems your method numberOfRowsInSection is not implemented.

Try to add this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
{
    return [self.myArray count];
}
```

Of course your ViewController have to be delegated for UITableViewDataSource and UItableViewDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [self.yourArry count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//Configure Cell

cell.textLabel.text = self.yourArry[indexPath.row]; 

return cell;
```

}

Comment: it's the sample of just appcoda tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
{
    return [self.myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell=nil;
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text =[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
        return cell;
 }
```

Comment: If u like my answer so please accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using a pointer to an `NSString` (or what object you are trying to make)

```
NSString *string = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Make sure you have the count of cell in the tableview set like so

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
{
    return self.myArray.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step One.

> In YourViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

> In YourViewController.m

```
#import "YourViewController.h"

@interface YourViewController ()
{
    UITableView * YourTableview;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 YourTableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 300, 500) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
YourTableview.delegate=self;
YourTableview.dataSource=self;
  [self.view addSubview:YourTableview];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
 return 5;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       static NSString * CellIdentifier=@"Cellid";

       UITableViewCell * SoftCell=[YourTableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!SoftCell)
        {
      SoftCell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
     textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
        return SoftCell;
}
```